# Calling child process and functional programming

Tags: python, functional-programming, mutability

Is it possible to avoid side effects and still create a child process? Example:

```
from subprocess import call

def ls(directory):
    return call("ls %s" % directory, shell=True)
```

If isn't possible, how functional languages make such operations?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you want here as immutable ?

Comment: Sorry, i made a confusion. I updated the question.

Comment: The side effect being the printing of the directory contents?

Comment: Yes... this is considered an side effect, right?

Comment: Yes just checking.

Comment: you can go pure and read about haskell monads and safe side-effects (will give you headaches, and you have to learn some haskel, but it's great stuff!), or you can go with lets say common lisp camp and write what you can in functional style, and those last 3 world interacting functions in imperative style with some functional api on top of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In functional languages creating child processes and doing anything like the one given is not a pure function it has side effects

In functional languages there are impure functions aswell but it would try to minimise code in impure functions and make the fact that a function is impure explicit. You may read about [IO monads](https://wiki.haskell.org/IO_inside)

Considering **Haskell** being the most functional language for example,it explicitly says it has side effects on its signature/declaration for `createProcess` function

```
createProcess :: CreateProcess -> IO (Maybe Handle, Maybe Handle, Maybe Handle, ProcessHandle)
```

The **IO** explicitly says it  has side effects

If you just need to avoid the out put you may do it like this

```
import os
import subprocess

FNULL = open(os.devnull, 'w')

def ls(directory):
    return subprocess.call(['ls',directory], stdout=FNULL, stderr=FNULL)
```